# Rails: show only specific objects inside a form select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form which I'm creating tokens for users. First I find all the users `@users = User.order('name ASC')` inside a controller. Then inside the create token form I have a select field from which I'm trying to show only the users that don't have a token:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% if user.token.blank? %>
    <%= f.input :user_id, collection: user, label: "Associate with", value_method: :id, :include_blank => "Select a user"  %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

But for some reason I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `to_a' for #<User:0x00007f95a54086b0>
Did you mean?  to_s
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: *"`f.input :user_id, collection: user`"* `user` is not a collection, but an instance of `User`.

Comment: You can simplify the above iteration by using `@users.reject(&:token?).each` if the collection is already loaded or `@user.where.not(token: '').each` if it's not yet loaded to limit the query further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE.
Just to clarify stuff. You get this error because you pass one single user as a collection to the input. And expecting collection it will try to convert whatever you passed to array. But it won't be able to properly convert a single user to array. So you should have passed a collection of users instead. Like this:

```
<%= f.input :user_id, collection: @users, label: "Associate with", value_method: :id, :include_blank => "Select a user"  %>
```

Of course, doing this you will need to have the users without tokens already assigned to your `@users` variable.

Or as I understand your problem, I can offer an alternative:

So assuming users without a token have `token` column set to nil you can do something like this:

```
<%= f.select :users, options_for_select(@users.where(token: nil).pluck(:name, :id)), include_blank: true %>
```

This will eliminate your need to iterate @users explicitly and to create an input for each of them i.e. the code above should replace this completely

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% if user.token.blank? %>
    <%= f.input :user_id, collection: user, label: "Associate with", value_method: :id, :include_blank => "Select a user"  %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Of course feel free to adjust that `select` helper as you need.

If you do not need `@users` with tokens anywhere in the current controller action or form, you should consider assigning `@users = User.where(token: nil)` right in your controller action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @VAD, unfortunately there is no token column at the users table, I'm trying to accomplish this thru associations: `token.rb = belongs_to :user` `user.rb = has_one :token`. so then I can do something like this from a loop `if user.token.blank?`

Comment: Then you may want to request your @users like this `@users =  User.left_outer_joins(:token).where(tokens: { id: nil })`. This will take all the users without tokens associated to them

Comment: @Theopap I updated my answer to clarify the problem

Answer (score 0):

@users should already contain the users who do not have a token to do so:

```
<%= f.input :user_id, collection: @users, label: "Associate with", value_method: :id, :include_blank => "Select a user"  %>
```